# Specifying a socket streaming source for a secured websocket(wss) using Apache flink

Tags: java, sockets, apache-flink

I have a project requirement where I am supposed to stream events coming in regularly via the given example api(this is a tampered url):

**wss://brisbane.unipulse.com.au:443/OutboundInterfaces/outbound/statements**

However, while trying to use the function:

```
    DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("wss://brisbane.unipulse.com.au:443/OutboundInterfaces/outbound/statements", port, "\n");
```

I get an unknown host exception.

Could anyone please help me to twist the url in a way where I can successfully start receiving the events in my application.

**OR**

Is there any other function which is used to process events in flink ?

Comment: We cannot help you with this. Somebody provided you with a url with an unknown hostname. I just checked it and it's really unknown. We can't invent a fix for that url, you'll have to get a working one.

Comment: @f1sh I tampered the url since I am not supposed to expose it on here. All I want to know is what part of the url am I supposed to add in the first parameter of the function.

Comment: @f1sh Seems like the function which I am trying to use does not supports TLS and only supports plain TCP which is the reason I am getting the unknown host exception.